# Перевод десятичного числа в двоичное число с помощью метода two's complement

Tags: c++

Пишу простенькую программу с помощью метода two's complement, получается своеобразная ошибка.

Так вот, при использовании "point++", в середине двоичного числа(как раз там, где должен быть пробел) появляется число 824 (при вводе 148 получается число 10082410100 ). При комментировании "point++" ошибки не возникает, но отсутствует пробел. Ожидал увидеть 10010100, а не 10082410100.

Заранее спасибо за помощь. Это мой первый вопрос, если возможно, укажите на ошибки в описании проблемы.

Фрагмент кода:

```
int main()
{


    std::cout << "Hello. Enter your number:";
    int x, point{1};
    std::cin >> x;

    for (int i = 128; i >= 1; )
    {
        if ((point != 4))
        {
            x >= i ? std::cout << '1' : std::cout << '0';
            x >= i ? x -= i : x = x;
        }
        else
        {
            x >= i ? std::cout << ' 1' : std::cout << ' 0';
            x >= i ? x -= i : x = x;
        }
        i /= 2;
        //point++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что `' 1'` воспринимается как двухбайтное число. Ну не бывает один *символ* (а в одинарных кавычках - значит, символ) из *двух*.

Да и вообще ваш код лучше переписать -

```
std::cout << "Hello. Enter your number:";
int x;
std::cin >> x;

for (int i = 128, point = 1; i >= 1; i /= 2)
{
    if (point++ == 4) std::cout << ' ';
    std::cout << (x >= i ? x-=i, 1 : 0);
}
```

Так и понятнее, и короче, нет? Только вот кажется мне, что с начальным значением `point` вы ошиблись, и оно должно быть равно **0**.